# How to Get remoteHost java

Tags: java

I'm trying to get a client's hostname,
I use this code:

```
public String GetHostIP(HttpServletRequest request) throws UnknownHostException {
        String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        System.out.println("remoteAddress ipAddress is : " + ipAddress);
        try {
            InetAddress Adress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
            clientHostName = Adress.getHostName();
            System.out.println("Host name is " + clientHostName);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return clientHostName;
    }
```

My question is, why I have same result whatever the host connected

> remoteAddress ipAddress is : 10.8.100.30 Host name is: 10.8.100.30

Thanks !

Comment: Hint: read about java style guides. Variables dont start with uppercase letters. That is highly confusing! Hint x2: don't make assumptions about the libraries you are using. Read their javadoc. Because typically, everything you will need to know is already documented there. And maybe a hundred times in this community, because people prefer to ask here, instead of doing some prior research ;-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName()) (boldface mine):

> `public String getHostName()`
>
> Gets the host name for this IP address.
>   If this `InetAddress` was created with a host name, this host name will be remembered and returned; otherwise, a reverse name lookup will be performed and the result will be returned based on the system configured name lookup service. If a lookup of the name service is required, call `getCanonicalHostName`.
>
> If there is a security manager, its `checkConnect` method is first called with the hostname and -1 as its arguments to see if the operation is allowed. **If the operation is not allowed, it will return the textual representation of the IP address.**

[This](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html#checkConnect(java.lang.String,%20int)) is the relevant documentation of `checkConnect`.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I'm looking for